# Conceptual - building classes with independent components

Tags: c#, oop

Beginner class design conceptual question here.

Say I want to represent an invoice with an object. Conceptually, you could say that an invoice is made up of two types of information - header information (like customer name, invoice date, invoice number), and line item information. Sometimes my application just needs to access header information, sometimes it just needs access to line item information. All information is not always necessary, so retrieving line items when you really only needs a date seems like like a waste of resources.

In attempting to adhere to good design principles, would it be best to define this as two separate classes that are instantiated at the same time when all information is needed? Is there a better way?

Something about treating one real-world thing like two objects doesn't seem quite right to me.

Comment: Have you thought about declaring *three* classes for this? One `InvoiceHeader` class, one `InvoiceContent` class, and one `Invoice` class that contains an instance of each of the other two classes? Do not think of it as treating one real-world thing like n objects; the header and the content are real-world things, as well, albeit not necessarily physically separable.

Comment: I did think about something along those lines, but thought it might involve code duplication. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I've written a simple example; no code duplication there, as you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the information you need separately into separate classes, and create one `Invoice` class that is composed of all the information involved. Do not think of the invoice as "one real-world thing" just because it (in paper form) cannot be physically separated; logical things such as the header of a letter can be distinct "real-world things", as well.

As simplified (because it does not properly check for invalid values, as it should) example:

```
public class InvoiceHeader
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceBody
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    private readonly InvoiceHeader header = new InvoiceHeader();

    public InvoiceHeader Header {
        get {
            return header;
        }
    }

    private readonly InvoiceBody body = new InvoiceBody();

    public InvoiceBody Body {
        get {
            return body;
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to further split this up as required - e.g. you might want to use a `Customer` object with some more information such as the address instead of the `string` property for the customer name, and the invoice body may or may not need to contain a list of items considered in the invoice.

Comment: Thanks! Does this approach have a common name? You mentioned 'composition' in a comment that has since been deleted. Would this be considered composition?

Comment: @brainbolt: Yes, I would call that 'composition', but 'composition' generally refers to assembling several classes by making instances of one or more classes fields of a surrounding class.